# Что такое выморочь?

Tags: словарь

Собственно, весь вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контекст? Собственно, весь ответ.

Если речь идет об имуществе, то это может быть разговорным синонимом выморочному имуществу - принадлежавшему умершему лицу не оставившему после себя за вещания и не имеющему законных заявленных наследников. Обычно оно обращается в доход государства. 
Еще, кажется, способ ювелирно-декоративной обработки металлов (возможно что-то сродни чернению) - но это не уверен. Отсюда "морозная выморочь" - ледяные "трещинки" на поверхности земли или стекла. 
Но в народном языке могло нести совершенно другой смысл, правда связанный со смерть, мором. Выморочная деревня - где не осталось населения по причине смерти всех жителей. Иногда - и переносно: дереdня, которую покинуло населения. Выморочное место - гиблое и т.д.  Или несчастье, смертельная напасть. Или то, что явилось результатом выморачивания (от слова "морочить [голову]"). Все эти значения могут передаваться словом "выморочь". Что фиксируются в интернете. И самое смешное - это еще и глагол. В значении - "вымарай".

Все указанные значения лежат за рамками общелитературного языка - нормативными словарями не фиксируются.

Comment: Всё так: морозная выморочь.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете ввиду глагол, наподобие **высечь**, **выволочь**, то, вероятнее всего, **выморочь** - заморить голодом (от вымаривать), но эта старая форма ныне вряд ли употребляется. Если вы имеете в виду существительное, наподобие **сволочь**, **мелочь**, то это будет некая, заморенная голодом сущность. Это первое значение. А второе можно вывести от юридического понятия **выморочное наследство** - имущество, оставшееся без наследников после смерти владельца. Возможно,**выморочь** - это сокращённая форма данного понятия - **выморочное наследство**, употребляемая в разговорной форме. Например, полицейские говорят: " Опять мне "висяк" попался!" Вполне возможно, что так же и нотариус может посетовать: "Опять мне **выморочь** попалась!" - то есть наследство без наследников.

Comment: Почему обязательно голодом-то?

Comment: Не обязательно, конечно, можно и смехом уморить, но как-то устоялось выражение в моём сознании: если морят, то голодом.